# Can I use node.js / socket.io with my PHP application?

Tags: php, node.js, apache

I have written an application in PHP with a progress bar for a long running script. Right now I am manually updating the progress bar by repeatedly calling a PHP script through Ajax.

However, this seems load intensive, I have been reading that something like socket.io can help reduce server load. Would any one have any advice on starting points for integrating socket.io with my PHP application? Right now I am running it on apache.

Comment: it's only load intensive if it takes time to calculate the progress.  I have code that does 50k queries a second, if it takes a fraction of a millisecond to get the progress I doubt it will be an issue.

Comment: It is not, it is a quick calculation. My only concern is that I am constantly requesting from the database, instead of the database "pushing" when a change is made. Which is why I thought of node.js, I have also heard of something called kafka?

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be a big deal unless you have shared hosting or some kind of bandwidth restrictions.  Like I mentioned I have a production server that makes literally millions of searches an hour and it still hosts 3 websites, some of which have their own stuff going on.  My server has 12 duo cores and 48gb of ram, but other then that I dont see it being an "issue".  Now if we are on to what is better, obviously pushing is better but that is not so much a php problem.  I think node would be good for it, I keep trying to come up with reasons to use node on my stuff so I can learn it

Comment: Id also say give any new technology a shot, I was only speaking form a "will it work without any major issues" standpoint.